# Indent html table row

Tags: html, css

I have a table in my html page and I want to make indentation on the last row of the table, after many search found nothing with css or html attr!

the table looks like this:

```
+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| a        | foo | 100 | 300 | 
| b        | bar | 200 | 400 | 
| Sum      | 300 | 700 |-----+ 
+----------+-----+-----+
```

and want to make the last row indent to be something like this:

```
+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| a        | foo | 100 | 300 | 
| b        | bar | 200 | 400 | 
+----------| Sum | 300 | 700 |
           +-----+-----+-----+
```

I was tried to use **padding-left** on **tr** and **td** but nothing happened

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You can try to add a first empty `cell <td>` to the last row.

Comment: Please include the code for your HTML and CSS so we can "see" where the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: @AniketG in the last line of my question I said that "I was tried to use padding-left on tr and td but nothing happened"; However, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply leave the first cell of the last row empty and remove its border.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.noBrd {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noBrd"></td>
    <td>Sum</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>700</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank's that no border will solve the problem in some way, but I have to add some empty cell to table to achieve it, I was try to find some sort of offset or padding like way!, buy anyway this is the working solution and thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
</tr>
 <tr style="padding-left:5px;border-width:1px;border-color:Red;">
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
</tr>
 <tr style="padding-left:5px;border:1px none Black;">
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
  <td>AB</td>
</tr>
```

This is another example of table.

Comment: And how do you know, what HTML will support?